# biber generate empty bbl file

Tags: biblatex, biber

I use `biblatex` with `biber` as its backend. My code is following (`test.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
Test test test \cite{Lee2009a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and `ref.bib` is

```
@article{Lee2009a,
    author  = {Lee, Geun},
    journal = {The Korean Journal of Defense Analysis},
    number  = {2},
    pages   = {205--218},
    title   = {{A Theory of Soft Power and Korea's Soft Power Strategy}},
    volume  = {21},
    year    = {2009}
}
```

I run `biber` after `pdflatex`. However, it only gives an empty bbl file.
The **whole** blg file is

```
[0] Config.pm:354> INFO - This is Biber 2.7
[1] Config.pm:357> INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
[80] biber-MSWIN32:303> INFO - === 
[123] Biber.pm:359> INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
[282] Biber.pm:835> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[314] Biber.pm:3670> INFO - Processing section 0
[352] Biber.pm:3840> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'ref.bib' for section 0
```

Compiling on the command line, `biber test` will give the following things on cmd:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.7
INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'ref.bib' for section 0
```

`biber --debug test` will give (`祥东` is my user name)

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.7
INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
INFO - DEBUG mode: all messages are logged to 'test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'ref.bib' for section 0
write_file 'C:\Users\祥东\AppData\Local\Temp\tlZld3jtIt\ref.bib_8456.utf8' - sysopen: No such file or directory at C:\Users\祥东\AppData\Local\Temp\par-cfe9b6ab\cache-2aa0b74e6d5e75f8e71a4b8c9501a9c7c24ddbf0\inc\lib/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm line 1428.
```

`ref.bib_8456.utf8` in the last line may change at different run.

All the file are stored in a folder named `testbib` on my desktop.

Platform: TeX Live 2017, biblatex 3.7 and biber 2.7 on Windows 10.

Comment: Does your blg really contain only this lines? Where is the tex and bib-file stored?

Comment: Yes. It seems strange, but is really the whole blg file. All files are in the same directory.

Comment: But how is the directory named? And how exactly do you call biber? Did you try on a command line in this directory?

Comment: How exactly do you run pdflatex and biber? Have you tried on the command line? (don't remember what thye renamed it to in Win10)

Comment: Is `biber` important to you? I never could get it to work and find `bibtex` does everything I need.

Comment: I just want to try a new thing... By the way, `bibtex` works normally on my system.

Comment: Try to compile biber directly on a command line and not through your batch file.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer BibTeX is considered a 'legacy' backend now. The full set of features is only supported by Biber. So especially in new documents people should try and use Biber.

Comment: @moewe I consider my own backend legacy, too ;)

Comment: Try running without the `@echo off` so you can see more messages.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I have tried to compile on a command line directly, and it gives the same result.

Comment: @Stone-Zeng What does the command line tells you when you run `biber test`?

Comment: Try running with the `--debug` flag, i.e. `biber --debug test` and check what the `.blg` contains. The log should be more verbose then.

Comment: I knew it that you have something unusual in your path name.  Try to relocate biber to a location without chinese (?) chars. See here https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/70

Comment: Any news here? If the Chinese characters were the problem you might want to file a bug report https://github.com/plk/biber/issues. If the problem was somewhere else, could you find a way to isolate it further?

Comment: Any news here? Did you get things running in the end?

Comment: Do you have any news for us?

Comment: If you have a work-around, why not post it as an answer, so people can see that it is a possible solution?=

Comment: @moewe OK. And I have found something wrong in my solution so I remove it. I will add an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

With the [hint](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/70) from @Ulrike Fischer, I have some solutions:

Change a **user** environment variable named `TEMP` and `TMP`. Their original value should be

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

It is actually `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp`. Then modify it to

```
%SystemRoot%\TEMP;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Now it is `C:\WINDOWS\temp;C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp`.

Then run

```
biber --cache
```

to generate cache files. It will take sometime and then show the current cache location.

(You can run `biber <filename>` as normal. It will generate the cache files automatically)

Now `biber` can run normally.

More information can be found in section 4.2 in `biber` manual (v2.7).

**Environment variables**

You may find it in `Control panel` > `System` > `Advanced system settings` > `Environment variables...`. The *user environment variables* `TEMP` and `TMP` can be found at the top panel.

**Note**

I'm not sure whether this way is OK because it has changed the system behaviour.